# Why search ignores synonyms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search for a phrase and get all results (including synonym results).

I configured my index as follow:

```
         "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_graph_synonyms": {
                            "type": "synonym_graph",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "Cosmos, Universe",
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_search_time_analyzer": {
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "stemmer",
                                "my_graph_synonyms"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "standard",
                    "search_analyzer": "my_search_time_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
```

I added 2 documents to the index:

```
PUT demo_idx/_doc/1
{
  "content": "Cosmos A Spacetime Odyssey is a 2014 American science documentary television series."
}

PUT demo_idx/_doc/2
{
  "content": "Universe A Spacetime Odyssey is a 2014 American science documentary television series."
}
```

I run the following search:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":
                    [{
                        "match": {
                            "content": {
                                "query": "Cosmos",
                            }
                        }
                    }]
            }
        }
```

I expected to get 2 results (following the synonyms) but I got only one.

How can I run the search query (while using the synonyms) and get 2 results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to the `stemmer` filter, if you remove this and index your data again, it will return you both documents,

You can use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to check the tokens generated by your analyzer, and you can see for `Cosmos` it generates below tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "univers", // Note this
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "cosmo",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

While `standard` tokenizer which is used at index time, creates `Universe` for `Universe` without stemming it, hence it doesn't match your search terms generated by `search_analyzer`.

Comment: Is it possible to get 2 results, and the second result will get smaller score ?

Comment: @user3668129, yes if you remove your stemmer filter, you get both results, but score is exactly same as your search term is just one word and that too is synonym, also your both the documents are exatcly same apart from synonym, if you add change them little bit, you will get different score